# Force mysql to start a query from the bottom of the table

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I run a mysql query starting from the bottom of the table to the top without adding an incrementing column?

I have an history of pages visited by the user and I want to show them with the most recently visited first, and I only record the url, I do not record the time or anything else.

Do I have to add a column with incrementing numbers or something like that or is there a way to run the query from the bottom of the table to the top?

And if I do have to add a column what's the best choice?

I found this similar question but it doesn't answer my question but I thought I would link it here:
[Scanning a mysql table from the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857720/scanning-a-mysql-table-from-the-bottom)

Comment: Until you have defined some particular order - there is no "top" or "bottom"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include some kind of order, there is no guarantee that items are ordered in the table in the same order they are inserted.

It's not an ordered list like excel.

You should add a CreatedDate column, then `ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC`

Comment: I will add a timestamp column then
Thank you

Comment: @JoãoCastro, if this answer helped, mark it, or whichever answer helped the most as the answer.  And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @CaffGeek Do you know how I can run mySQL from top to bottom? My table looks like this -> `1,2,4,5,7,8,3` and I want the result to be `3,8,7,5,4,2,1` and DESC would not work in this case.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, tables do not have in inherent ordering.  There is no concept in SQL of the "top" or "bottom" of a table.  There is a concept of a order by for a result set, but that is different.

The simplest thing to do is to add an auto-increment column into the table.  This will guarantee that each row has a different value.  You can continue to insert only one value . . . the auto-increment is a default value.  When you pull from the table, use `order by id desc` to get the most recent additions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the `Order By` clause is that it applies to the results **after** the program has already searched the whole table, this makes the search super long when you have billions of records, (in my case it times out) the idea here is to force the program to start with the most recent records and add a `LIMIT` of let's `1000` and then show you the `1k` most recent records as the program reaches the limit without searching the whole table, you can see this approach works using the oldest records but not the other way.

Comment: You found a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
ORDER BY DESC
```

at the end of your SQL statement.

Comment: That is kind of what I was looking but for that to work you have to specify a column which I don't have and I didn't want to create.